# Simple math on SQL query results or on a datatable

Tags: c#, html, sql, datatable

Let's say I have a query that returns something simple like...

```
**TYPE**      **TOTAL**
A                2
B                4
```

And I want to do some math like A/(A+B) -> 2/(2+4) then display that on my website. Is that more feasible to do within the query or after when I have it stored in a datatable??

Comment: It is tough to give you a definitive answer based only on the snippet you gave.  You could do this in either place.

Comment: In my practice, I tend to leave data as raw as possible so that it can be manipulated in as many ways as I want going forward.  As Mr Biegeleisen said though, it's difficult to give an *answer* without having a more clear picture of your data, and how you plan to manipulate it as a whole

Comment: I'm thinking I'm just going to edit my SQL statement to include the math..

Comment: I basically have two match types, A or B. So my statement is really just select match_type as type, count(*) as total from tableName;

Comment: I don't see how you can even take two different entries in a single query. However you can perform two SELECT statements to find the values 2 and 4, group them using the parentheses (), and perform the operation using this grouping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try something like this if you realy need to get it done in same way.

```
SELECT A/(A+B) FROM((SELECT total as A FROM TB WHERE type='A' LIMIT 1),(SELECT total as B FROM TB WHERE type='B' LIMIT 1))
```

Tested and working..

Comment: Hmmm this is helpful but A is not my total, A is a type. The total would be A + B. I'm looking to calculate A/total